How can I get "parent" node from PropertyGroup?
I have a node that contains a collection of strings:
import bpy

def UpdateTxt(self, context):
    pass

class Line(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    txt: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Text", default="", update=UpdateTxt)

class NodeEx(bpy.types.Node):
    bl_idname = 'NodeEx'
    bl_label = "CustomNode123"
    bl_width_default = 200
    lines: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Line)
    def init(self, context):
        for cyc in range(4):
            ci = self.lines.add()
            ci.name = str(cyc)
    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        colList = layout.column()
        for ci in self.lines:
            colList.prop(ci,'txt', text="")

bpy.utils.register_class(Line)
bpy.utils.register_class(NodeEx)

The property has an 'update' method, which will be called every time a 'txt' in a group in a collection is updated. In this method, self will contain the node's collection item.
When I update a string, how does an item determine which node it belongs to?

def UpdateTxt(self, context):
    self.???.??.label = "CustomNode456"  # how?

One possible solution is to maintain a reference while filling the collection:
def UpdateTxt(self, context):
    dict_selfToNode[self].label = "CustomNode456"

...

dict_selfToNode = {}

class NodeEx(bpy.types.Node):
    ...
    def init(self, context):
        for cyc in range(4):
            ci = self.lines.add()
            dict_selfToNode[ci] = self #<-- here
            ci.name = str(cyc)
    ...

This workaround does work, but it does not scale to large projects. For example, after a certain number of items, the address of the first item changes, making it impossible to find in the dictionary. That's why I’m seeking an alternative.
How can I access the "owner" or parent of a PropertyGroup?
Here's a complete and reproducible code example. Note that at least one node editor area (Compositor, Geometry Nodes, Shader Editor, etc.) needs to be open before running the script.
import bpy

class BseTree(bpy.types.NodeTree):
    bl_idname = 'BseNodeTree'
    bl_label = "Bse Node Tree"
    bl_icon = 'SNAP_FACE'

def CnUpdateTxt(self, context):
    try:
        ndSelf = self.idk.how
    except Exception as ex:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc()[:-1])
        print("   Omg ^ See source")
    txt_message_with_important_information_about_node = 'f"You changed a line from a node named \"{ndSelf.name}\""'
    def PopupMessage(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text=txt_message_with_important_information_about_node, icon='INFO')
    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(PopupMessage, title='f"{ndSelf.name}"', icon='NONE')
    #ndSelf.label = txt_message_with_important_information_about_node
class CnLine(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    txt: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Text", default="", update=CnUpdateTxt)
class BseNode(bpy.types.Node):
    bl_idname = 'BseNode'
    bl_label = "CustomNode123"
    bl_width_default = 265
    lines: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=CnLine)
    def draw_label(self):
        return f"I'm a \"{self.name}\" node!"
    def init(self, context):
        for cyc in range(3):
            ci = self.lines.add()
            ci.name = str(cyc)
    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        colList = layout.column(align=True)
        for ci in self.lines:
            colList.prop(ci,'txt', text="")

def register():
    for dv in dict(globals()).values():
        if dv.__class__.__name__.lstrip("_") in {"RNAMeta", "RNAMetaPropGroup"}:
            bpy.utils.register_class(dv)
    for wn in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        for ar in wn.screen.areas:
            if ar.type=='NODE_EDITOR':
                if ar.spaces[0].type=='NODE_EDITOR':
                    ar.ui_type = BseTree.bl_idname
                    tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("Bse") or bpy.data.node_groups.new("Bse", BseTree.bl_idname)
                    ar.spaces[0].node_tree = tree
                    tree.nodes.clear()
                    nd = tree.nodes.new(BseNode.bl_idname)
                    nd.name = "first_node.001"
                    nd.select = False
                    nd.lines[1]['txt'] = "Edit me pls"
                    nd = tree.nodes.new(BseNode.bl_idname)
                    nd.name = "second_node.002"
                    nd.location.x = -300
                    nd.select = False
                    nd.lines[1]['txt'] = "The edited line must know its node --->"
if __name__=="__main__":
    register()

Upd:
Omg, I completely forgot that context has node. So another possible non-ideal solution is
def UpdateTxt(self, context):
    ndSelf = context.node
    ...

but this does not work in situations where the line was cleared via Backspace key or the line content was changed via the console:


In some types that PointerProperty supported, you can implement. But PointerProperty unsupport bpy.types.Node.
even if you can assign a blender python instance to the group, when you perform undo/redo, blender will make that object unable to access (Invalid pointer) , even will crash blender when you access.

I don't think Blender inherently stores a back-reference from a PropertyGroup item to its parent object.
Maybe add a PointerProperty to the Line PropertyGroup to store a reference to the parent node.
Or if all the parent and child nodes are hierarchal then you could build a search tree method (likely to be slow though) - can you expand on the relations of your classes please.

It would be much easier to help if you presented a full working example, otherwise the code can't be easily copy-pasted and tested. Or did you? I never implemented my own node trees, but there's no poll check for the tree type in your example which suggests you stripped the code from boilerplate.

I tried running the added code, but despite the code inside register() function, I have to manually switch to BSE node editor, create a tree, it is empty, and I can't add any node, testing on Blender 4.2. Apparently @HarryMcKenzie was able to run it, but I'm a special needs person.

@MarkusvonBroady Yeah, it doesn’t work unless you have one of the node editors open, which then switches to the new custom BseNodeTree editor when you run the script and adds the nodes. I added this note into the question before running the script.

@HarryMcKenzie Aah! Thanks! I should have figured it out based on iterating over screen's areas...

path_from_id does not work on subproperties of a custom node #51096

a design limitation: you can never go from current property to parent


working this around by providing special path functions to properties, which are iterating over all possible parents and gives path to the parent which actually hold the property

class CnLine(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    txt: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Text", default="", update=CnUpdateTxt)
    
    def get_parent_node(self):
        for node in self.id_data.nodes:

            if node.bl_idname != 'BseNode':
                continue

            for line in node.lines:
                if line.as_pointer() == self.as_pointer():
                    return node

        raise Exception('Should not be.')


What's wrong with checking if line == self: without as_pointer()?

I was unsure about the comparison implementation for the bpy_struct but it is the same: pyrna_struct_as_pointer,  pyrna_struct_compare. Also wanted something explicit and idiomatic as self is line or id(self) == id(line).

To ensure it is not compared as a dictionary like IDP_EqualsProperties_ex.

It’s not possible to directly reference a node’s parent from a PropertyGroup without some form of indirect reference. The PropertyGroup itself does not inherently know about the node tree or its nodes. Therefore, I suggest adding a reference, such as a unique ID for the node, to each line (ci.node_unique_id = self["unique_id"]). Then, on update, loop through all the nodes to compare the ID.
Note that this approach is particularly robust in situations where nodes may be renamed, relocated, or restructured. It provides a consistent and reliable point of reference for nodes, regardless of their location or level in the hierarchy.
import bpy
import uuid

class BseTree(bpy.types.NodeTree):
    bl_idname = 'BseNodeTree'
    bl_label = "Bse Node Tree"
    bl_icon = 'SNAP_FACE'

class CnLine(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    txt: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Text", default="", update=lambda self, context: self.update_txt(context))
    node_unique_id: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Node Unique ID", default="")

    def update_txt(self, context):
        tree = context.space_data.node_tree
        ndSelf = next((node for node in tree.nodes if node.get("unique_id") == self.node_unique_id))
        txt_message_with_important_information_about_node = f"You changed a line from a node named \"{ndSelf.name}\""
        def PopupMessage(self, context):
            self.layout.label(text=txt_message_with_important_information_about_node, icon='INFO')
        bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(PopupMessage, title=f"{ndSelf.name}", icon='NONE')

class BseNode(bpy.types.Node):
    bl_idname = 'BseNode'
    bl_label = "CustomNode123"
    bl_width_default = 265
    lines: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=CnLine)

    def init(self, context):
        self["unique_id"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        for cyc in range(3):
            ci = self.lines.add()
            ci.name = str(cyc)
            ci.node_unique_id = self["unique_id"]

    def draw_label(self):
        return f"I'm a \"{self.name}\" node!"

    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        colList = layout.column(align=True)
        for ci in self.lines:
            colList.prop(ci, 'txt', text="")

def register():
    for dv in dict(globals()).values():
        if dv.__class__.__name__ in {"RNAMeta", "RNAMetaPropGroup"}:
            bpy.utils.register_class(dv)
    for wn in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        for ar in wn.screen.areas:
            if ar.type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
                if ar.spaces[0].type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
                    ar.ui_type = BseTree.bl_idname
                    tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get("Bse") or bpy.data.node_groups.new("Bse", BseTree.bl_idname)
                    ar.spaces[0].node_tree = tree
                    tree.nodes.clear()
                    nd = tree.nodes.new(BseNode.bl_idname)
                    nd.name = "first_node.001"
                    nd.select = False
                    nd.lines[1]['txt'] = "Edit me pls"
                    nd = tree.nodes.new(BseNode.bl_idname)
                    nd.name = "second_node.002"
                    nd.location.x = -300
                    nd.select = False
                    nd.lines[1]['txt'] = "The edited line must know its node --->"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


I think the problem with pointers is that they aren't "long-lived" which you can see after trying to modify a string after using CTRL+Z (undo), which invalidates some objects and makes the pointed out-of-date.

Maybe indeed use a pointer, but if it fails, then go through all nodes of this type, and recreate pointers. It's potentially slow, but only in rare situations. Of course you could hold a node name and see if it hasn't changed. If not, good, you restore pointer fast. Otherwise loop on all nodes of the type.

@MarkusvonBroady how about now using unique_id? hehe

Using context.space_data.node_tree is an interesting alternative to unwave's self.id_data, probably both are OK. I'd remove the default None from next(), so you get an error earlier if nothing is found. And finally I don't know how reliable is the unique_id, ideally someone uses this solution and reports back if he ever gets an error.  As I mentioned earlier, you could still have a pointer and check its validity, but on second thought, a string update happens rarely, the number of nodes should be well below a million, so maybe there is no need for an optimization...

@MarkusvonBroady cool thank you for your feedback! :)
